How can I efficiently count the number of occurrences of multiple specific characters within a given range of a string in Python?
I have a long text file and need to count occurrences of several specific characters (e.g., 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') within a specified range of lines. Manually iterating through each line is too slow. What is an efficient method to achieve this?
I tried iterating through each line in the specified range and using the count() method for each character. My code looked something like this:
char_counts = {char: 0 for char in "aeiou"}
with open("large_text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[start_line:end_line]
    for line in lines:
        for char in char_counts:
            char_counts[char] += line.count(char)

I expected this to efficiently count the occurrences of each specified character within the range. However, it turned out to be slower than anticipated, especially for large files and ranges. I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter?

Define "efficient".

You definitely need to read every single line to count occurrences of characters.

If your text file is very large, you may not want to use readlines() as this will read the entire file into memory. It would be potentially faster to read one line at a time skipping until you reach the first line of interest. Then when you've reached the last line of interest, you can break your loop.
Something like this:
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import time

FILENAME = Path("~/words.txt").expanduser()
VOWELS = set("AEIOUaeiou")


def count_vowels(file: Path, start: int, end: int) -> dict[str, int]:
    counter: Counter = Counter()
    with file.open() as fd:
        for _ in range(start):
            if not fd.readline():
                break  # EOF
        else:
            for _ in range(start, end):
                if line := fd.readline():
                    counter.update(line)
                else:
                    break  # EOF
    return {k: v for k, v in counter.items() if k in VOWELS}


start = time.perf_counter()
result = count_vowels(FILENAME, 10_000, 20_000)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(result)
print(f"Duration={end-start:.4f}s")

Output:
{'A': 0, 'E': 0, 'I': 0, 'O': 0, 'U': 0, 'a': 17163, 'e': 6861, 'i': 10138, 'o': 6855, 'u': 2006}
Duration=0.0099s

Notes:
The file used in this test is comprised of >400,000 lines. All letters in the file happen to be in lowercase
Platform:
macOS Sonoma 14.5
Apple Silicon M2
Python 3.12.4


Rather than using the string count() method or a Counter, you count use the re module's findall() function, e.g.,
import re

def countvowels_re(fname, startline=None, endline=None):
    char_counts = {char: 0 for char in "aeiou"}
    with open(fname, "r") as fp:
        # read in all the data and join into a single string
        text = "".join(fp.readlines()[startline:endline])
        for char in char_counts:
            char_counts[char] += len(re.findall(char, text))
    return char_counts


Note that using findall to find each individual vowel in the whole text seems to be quicker than trying to find all the vowels together, e.g., re.findall("[aeiou"], text).

In a simple test on a fairly short file, I find that using re is faster than a similar method using a Counter (like in @SIGHUP's answer):
from collections import Counter

def countvowels_counter(fname, startline=None, endline=None):
    char_counts = {char: 0 for char in "aeiou"}
    counter = Counter()
    with open(fname, "r") as fp:
        text = "".join(fp.readlines()[startline:endline])
        counter.update(text)
        for char in char_counts:
            char_counts[char] = counter.get(char, 0)
    return char_counts

Applying the above two functions on a text file with 2000000 characters generated with:
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

data = np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), (20000, 100))
np.savetxt("data.txt", data, fmt="%c", delimiter="")

I get:
%timeit countvowels_re("data.txt")
14.8 ms ± 380 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

and
%timeit countvowels_counter("data.txt")
68.2 ms ± 929 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

respectively.
